# Smarty Variable Declaration Error

Tags: php, smarty

I have the PHP code:

```
$uid = $xUS['id'];  // Current user id
$uname = $xUS['x_username'];          // Current user name
$ulink = '';  // Current user profile URL (leave blank for none)
$upic = $xUS['config_forum_avator_head'];                // Current user
$ismod = 0;                 // Is current user a moderator?
$sig = md5($uid . $uname . $ismod . 's79tvi40k95bs6mw');
$ssoParams = '&uid=' . $uid . "&uname=" .
urlencode($uname) . "&ulink=" .       urlencode($ulink) . "&upic=" . urlencode($upic) 
.   "&ismod=" . $ismod . "&sig=" . $sig;</i>
```

My Smarty template file:

`<iframe width='550' height='500' src='http://chatroll.com/embed/chat/pibux-chatroom?id=tgybumotNmY&platform=php{$ssoParams}&w=$0' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>`

In this, the `{$ssoParams}` variable is returning a null value. Why? Please help out.

Answer (score 0):

Read Smarty docs for example: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.tpl#language.assigned.variables

You need to assign a variable like:

```
$smarty = new Smarty();
```

`$smarty->assign('ssoParams', $ssoParams); // assign(smarty var, PHP var);`
`$smarty->display('template_file.tpl');`

And of course you need to include smarty files, define templates etc.

For basic working example look example 2.9. here: 
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/installing.smarty.basic.tpl#id2778275

Comment: Strange. Check if your paths are correct. Like here: require_once(SMARTY_DIR . 'Smarty.class.php'); or use:
require_once('path/to/smarty/Smarty.class.php'); then also for template_dir, compile_dir etc. and use or uncomment this line so you should receive debug window. ($smarty->debugging = true;)
Also make sure you call the right template file. In this line use the name of your template file: $smarty->display('template_file.tpl'); Also try to CHMOD  templates_c directory to write permission. 755, 777 or anything like that.